# making same value of many input field as array of strings

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button. When user clicks on "add more", another input field is added, up to a maximum of 10. How can i take the value of each one of these input fields and put it in an array of strings on submit?

```
<div class="input_fields_wrap">

        <div class ="delivery-num-container">
        <button class="add_field_button btn btn-info btn-sm">Add More Numbers</button>
        <input type="text" name="delivery_number" value="{{admissions.delivery_number}}" class="form-control delivery-num-input" required pattern="[0-9]+" placeholder="ex(1524587....)"></div>
 </div>
```

jq code

```
var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

var x = 1; //initlal text box count
$(add_button).click(
    function(e) { //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
        $(wrapper).append('<div class="delivery-num-input"><input type="text" name="delivery_number" class="form-control delivery_number_plus"/><a href="#" class="remove_field btn btn-sm btn-danger">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
        }
    }
);

$(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", //user click on remove text
    function(e) { 
        e.preventDefault(); 
        $(this).parent('div').remove(); 
        x--;
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an array, loop over all of the inputs, and then append (ie. `push`) them to the newly created array:

```
var array = [];
wrapper.find('input').each(function(){
    array.push($(this).val())
})
```

Comment: i think here will push value even if empty one isn't it?

Comment: then just do check for it, if it is not empty then only push it to the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can query by tag and name, this way you can be more specific on what fields to look at here's a sample function you can use:

```
 function getValues(){

    var sample = [];
    $('input[name=delivery_number]').each(function(idx){
       sample.push($(this).val());
    });
   console.log(JSON.stringify(sample));
   return sample;
}
```